# how to apply AForge.Imaging.Filters even on a Unsupported Image Format

Tags: c#, exception, format, aforge

i use Afroge library version 1 like this

```
FiltersSequence filters = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.FiltersSequence();
filters.Add(new ColorFiltering(
                            new AForge.IntRange(0, redValue),
                            new AForge.IntRange(0, grnValue),
                            new AForge.IntRange(0, bluValue)));
...
filters.Add(new Threshold());
var image = filters.Apply( new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image));
```

on its version 1 it works well. but now on version 2.2.5 with the same image process gives me unsupported image format exception.
how to apply filters efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Write a new FilterSequance class, by applying required formate setting.
i cast the image format, using

```
 Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(new Bitmap(image));
```

and then apply the result to the Threshold filter.